# How to call a method on an object found with a BeanLocator

Tags: java, spring, object, liferay

I'm using Liferay but I guess it's more of a Spring question.

In Liferay, I'm in a JSP with :

```
<%@page import="com.liferay.portal.kernel.bean.PortletBeanLocatorUtil" %>
<c:set var="testUtil" value='<%= PortletBeanLocatorUtil.locate("another-web-app-portlet", "com.mycompany.test.Test") %>' />
```

In the JSP, I can write this JSTL code and this works :

```
${testUtil.test}
```

But I can't do this :

```
<% TestUtil test = PortletBeanLocatorUtil.locate("another-web-app-portlet", "com.mycompany.test.Test"); %>
```

Because it won't compile of course. TestUtil is not visible to this webapp (and I can't make it visible).

**The question is :
How can I call a method in a scriplet on my bean found with BeanLocator?**

I would like to do something like :

```
<% PortletBeanLocatorUtil.locate("another-web-app-portlet", "com.mycompany.test.Test").myMethod("my param value"); %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using Reflection

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;
<%
//getMethod expects method name along with the type of arguments - in this example it's expecting single parameter of type String
Method m = PortletBeanLocatorUtil.locate("another-web-app-portlet").getClass().getMethod("myMethod", String.Class ...)

m.invoke(PortletBeanLocatorUtil.locate("another-web-app-portlet"), new Object[] { new String("blah") });
%>
```

Comment: That's what I did.. That's not super fun to do but It's better than adding ton of scriptlets in JSPs I guess.

Comment: hmm but it will degrade the performance as the method calls/accessing fields will be slower as compared to direct calls.

Comment: But instead of having big JSP included and containing tons of methods in it, the methods will be compiled in JAVA... I think that it's a good trade.

Comment: I recommend you to read http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-dyn0603/ - skip to Reflection performance section

Comment: Thanks for the link! I'll keep this in mind, but in the example there was a lot of calls using Reflection, I'll have less than 3 or 4 by JSPs. But it's good to know that it can be like 100 times slower ;)